# function mktime() not working properly

Tags: php, string

I want to find first day of next month.
So i use

```
$firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-01', strtotime('first day of next month'));
```

but it was not working in server.
Then i found a question in stackoverflow. Solution use

```
 $firstDayNextMonth =`date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')-1,1,date('Y')))`
```

but that give wrong answer.

Comment: Can you describe not working ? And what is your server's version ?

Comment: What PHP version are you running on the server. Maybe upgrade it to be the same as on your local host?

Comment: `mktime()` has existed since PHP 4. I doubt the server's running an installation older than that...

Comment: what is the o/p you want so that we can give it working for lower php version

Comment: The mktime function might return false (or -1) which might be interpreted as an unix timestamp by date.

Comment: you want 2014-01-01 from 01-01-2014 ?

Comment: Well, first of all, you are doing `date('n')-1`, which gives you 12. As in previous month, now being 1, previous is 12.

Comment: For 'the first day of _next_ month', at least use `date('n')+1` instead of `date('n')-1`

Comment: @Ruud thank you for your valuable comment its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date('n')+1,1,date('Y')));

?>
```

[demo](http://3v4l.org/OaToh)